# Android Capturing an image From Camera Returns Empty Data

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera-intent

While Capturing image in android app intent return null each time. Please see below the code which I am using. I have tried multiple ways to get the permission as well as intent set but still I am unable to get data.

Action For Camera

```
 private void takePhotoFromCamera() {

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ObservationsView.this, 
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(),
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }else {
    String[] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    requestPermissions(permissionRequest, 8675309);
    checkPermission();
    }
}
```

And Here is the Response Code

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        Uri selectedImg = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Bundle extras;
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            selectedImg = data.getData();
            extras = data.getExtras();

            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        }

        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

            selectedImg = fileUri;


            // Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
                if (bmp != null) {
                    bmp = getBitmapFromUri(fileUri);
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bmp);


            Intent passPhoto = new Intent(this, Photo.class);
            passPhoto.putExtra("image",tempUri);

            passPhoto.putExtra("Caller", getIntent().getComponent().getClassName());
            startActivity(passPhoto);


        }
```

Comment: How are you taking data from camera `onActivityResult` result?

Comment: You don't need the returned `Intent` data. The image is at `fileUri`. You can get it from there.

Comment: What's the target version and are you facing the issue on some platforms or everywhere?

Comment: you don't need `CAMERA` permission to use default camera capture

Comment: @SalmanKhan I am testing on Samsung S5 and Android 6.0 but I am having same issue on other devices as well

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko camera permissions are already given. Can you please suggest if any further permission needs to be added

Comment: @RujulGandhi please see updated the code

Comment: `if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {...} else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {...}` don't you find this condition weird?

Comment: @DilshadAli see my answer and let me know if you need further clarification for the same.

Comment: @DilshadAli Forgot to update the Manifest file previously. Check it again and then try to run your application. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code for getting the image in all APIs -

```
 public void takePicture() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    getOutputMediaFile());
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }

 private File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getString(R.string.app_folder_name));

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }


        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                PROFILE_PIC + getString(R.string.pic_type));
    }
```

And on your onActivityResult -

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    imageView.setImageURI(file);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Also, you need to define the Provider in your Manifest.xml file -

```
  <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

And finally the provider_paths.xml will be as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Let me know in case you need any clarification.